# Tsere Pronunciation

Tags: hebrew

I recently refreshed my Hebrew reading and started studying Biblical Hebrew in order to enhance my davening, and study of Torah and Jewish music. It is within this context that I asked the below question yesterday (which was flagged as off-topic):

I have a question about the Sephardic pronunciation of the tsere vowel.

I learned that it is pronounced as "ei" or "ay" as in the English "hay", however, I think I may have also read somewhere that it is also sometimes pronounced as the "e" in "bed", in which case it would have the same sound as a segol.

Now I am learning the names of the hebrew letters, and according to the book I have, several of the names are spelled in hebrew using a tsere.

For instance ב is written בֵּית and ה is written as הֵא. At the same time in English my book writes that ב is "Bet" and  ה is "He"; and in a different book ה is "Hey". (I have the same question for ח, ט,  מ, פ, and ר as they all use a tsere in hebrew).

So my question is, which sound is the correct pronunciation for ב ,ה, and the other letters mentioned? For ב is the "e" in Bet pronounced "ay" as in hay (which would sound the same as "bait"), or "e" as in "bed"?

It is very confusing because, for instance, ג is written in English as Gimel, but the "e" here has to be like the "e" as in "bed" because it is written in hebrew with a seghol (גִּמֶּל).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are three main camps I know of: the tsere is pronounced e, unless it is followed by a yud, in which it is pronounced ey, it is always pronounced e, and it is always pronounced ey.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely correct pronunciation (see שפת אמת שפתי כהן by R' Bentzion Cohen) is an elongated e as in the word air (British pronunciation)
However following one's tradition is also acceptable. So, an Ashkenazi may pronounce it as ey and Sephardim may pronounce as e if they wish.